# Can I fix a "version GLIBC_2.14 not found" error without being sysadmin?

Tags: python, glibc, libc

I am trying to run a `setup.py` file on a remote machine in a Conda environment. I get the following error message:

```
    from torch.utils.cpp_extension import BuildExtension, CUDAExtension
  File "/home/pbrook/miniconda3/envs/super_resolution/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found
```

I found [one post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421642/libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found) that suggests that I don't have a high enough version of `libc6`.

My question: is it possible for me to update this and overcome my problem even if I am not the root user? Or do I have to ask the system admin to do this for me. I am new to using Conda environments, so I wasn't sure if this was something I could do within my Conda environment without having to bother the system admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question: is it possible for me to update this and overcome my problem even if I am not the root user?

Yes, in multiple ways. From easiest to more difficult:

1. You can download a build of `torch` intended to run on your system.
2. You could build `torch` from source on the target system.
3. You could install a second (newer) version of GLIBC in alternative location.

Comment: Thank you. So I will attempt the easiest option! Option 1 seems to imply that my version of `torch` is not the right one for my system. So how do I know which version of `torch` I need and is it possible for me to download it without root access?

Comment: @user1551817 To answer your questions, you need to tell us what system you have  on the remote machine. Also -- " is it possible for me to download it without root access?" -- presumably you've done it once to get `/home/pbrook/miniconda3/...` version (which is the wrong one), so you should be able to do it again.