# How do I install Pytorch 1.3.1 with CUDA enabled

Tags: python, pytorch, conda

I have a conda environment on my Ubuntu 16.04 system.

When I install Pytorch using:

```
conda install pytorch
```

and I try and run the script I need, I get the error message:

```
raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
```

From looking at forums, I see that this is because I have installed Pytorch without CUDA support.

I then tried:

```
conda install -c pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 pytorch
```

but now I get the error:

```
    from torch.utils.cpp_extension import BuildExtension, CUDAExtension
  File "/home/username/miniconda3/envs/super_resolution/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found
```

So it seems that these two installs are installing different versions of Pytorch(?). The first one that seemed to work was Pytorch 1.3.1.

My question: How do I install Pytorch with CUDA enabled, but ensure it is version `1.3.1` so that it works with my system?

Comment: What is your cuda version? Did you try with `9.0` or `10.0`? What is your OS?

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 16.04. With either cuda 8.0 or 10.0 I get the same error message.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke do you need to install CUDA on your OS in order to use it with `conda + Pytorch ` ? Yesterday I've heared that Pytorch conda installation comes with it's own CUDA.

Comment: Yes, you need CUDA capable device and cuda drivers installed.

Comment: Have you tried with `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.2 -c pytorch`?

Comment: Thank you. I just tried to do that, but I still got the same `GLIBC_2.14' not found message.

Comment: @user1551817 can you post the output of `apt policy libc6`?

Comment: hmmm it said "apt: invalid flag: policy"

Comment: @user1551817 Try an `apt-cache search libc` and see which versions are available. I'd suggest to install from there, but if it isn't available, I think you could try to install from this channel: `conda install -c pwwang glibc214 `.

Comment: @user1551817 did any of these options work?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. For `apt-cache search libc` I just get `-bash: apt-cache: command not found`. I am able to do the conda install, but then I still get the original message about `GLIBC_2.14 not found`.

Comment: What's the version of `glibc` on your machine (`ldd --version`)? You'll probably have to upgrade the _system_ glibc version _(upgrading conda env's `glibc` won't probably work)_, something like `apt-get install libc6`

Comment: When I try that I just get `-bash: apt-get: command not found`. I am not the root user, I don't know if that is relevant.

Comment: You need to be the root user or in the sudoers list (to use `sudo`) to upgrade the system library. You may look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491374/terminal-sudo-apt-get-command-not-found) for this error.

Comment: Okay thank you. Well I cannot use sudo on this system so it appears I will not be able to get Pytorch working? I was originally told that I would be okay with a different version of Pytorch that would be compatible for my system: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59545197/can-i-fix-a-version-glibc-2-14-not-found-error-without-being-sysadmin

Comment: It seems pytorch's precompiled binary [expects that `glibc`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/6607#issuecomment-381423063). You may try installing [older versions of pytorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/), but I'm not sure it'll work. Also, run [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/pytorch/master/torch/utils/collect_env.py) to understand more about your env.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205542/discussion-between-user1551817-and-kharshit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that your system is running Ubuntu 16.04, it comes with glibc installed. You can check your version by typing `ldd --version`.

Keep in mind that [PyTorch is compiled](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/is-glibc2-17-version-really-required/22178) on [CentOS which runs glibc version 2.17.](https://gist.github.com/wagenet/35adca1a032cec2999d47b6c40aa45b1)

Then check the [CUDA version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727688/how-to-get-the-cuda-version) installed on your system `nvcc --version`

Then install PyTorch as follows e.g. if your cuda version is 9.2:
`conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.2 -c pytorch`

If you get the glibc version error, try [installing an earlier version](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/) of PyTorch.

If neither of the above options work, then try [installing PyTorch from sources.](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#from-source)

If you would like to set a specific PyTorch version to install, please set it as <version_nr> in the below command:
`conda install pytorch=<version_nr> torchvision cudatoolkit=9.2 -c pytorch`

Comment: This installs the latest pytorch, not 1.3 specifically

Answer (score 4):

For CUDA 10.1:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
```

For CUDA 9.2:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.2 -c pytorch
```

For no CUDA:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you have solved your problem or not, but I have this exact same problem before because I was trying to install pytorch on a cluster and I don't have root access. You need to download glibc into your directoryand set the environmental variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to your local glibc https://stackoverflow.com/a/48650638/5662642.

To install glibc locally, I will point you to this thread that I read to solve my problem

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38317265/5662642 (instead of setting --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14 when installing, you might want to set it to other directory that you have access to). Hope it works for you